# .gitmodules changes with multiple git users, causing a constant headache

Tags: git, ssh, openssh

allow me to first of all say I'm a Git n00b and relatively new to version control entirely. We've done a good job of using Git in a Windows environemnt with Visual Studio so far, and all seems to be going well. However something that is annoying is the `.gitmodules` 'battle' we currently have on our hands.

If UserA creates a new sub-module, the path in `.gitmodules` for the 'origin' will look something like:

```
ssh://usera@myserver/Repositories/NewModule
```

When I, User B, pull the changes from the server I download a copy of `.gitmodules` with that entry. When I try to initialize the new sub-module I inevitably cannot download from myserver, because I'm userb and hold only my SSH key for userb. I end up having to change `.gitmodules` to reflect *my* username:

```
ssh://userb@myserver/Repositories/NewModule
```

And I will end up pushing this change.

Thus we end up with a recursive problem of us both changing the username from UserA to UserB or vice versa. When either of us pull/push to the server.

Any ideas how we can resolve this issue? Maybe a shared user account for us both simply for sub-modules? Can that be done? How? Any other ideas out there, or any one that has solved this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to install [Gitosis](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way) on myserver. Everyone's clone URL would then be the same, of the form `ssh://git@myserver:/path/to/repo.git`. Gitosis allows you to register developers' SSH keys and allows you to specify authentication and authorization rules.

You could also roll your own by hacking `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` on myserver and doing authorization through a modification of this [example update hook](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/update-hook-example.txt).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is 'check if you could use relative paths for submodules'.

The detailed answer is:
we have submodule that is being used by multiple apps. We have kept the submodule in the same repo.

The structure is like this,
repo

```
|-app1
|-app2
|-submod
```

When we clone the app the `app/.git/config` gets URL with current user like '`userA@repo.com`'. 
In the `.gitmodules` of apps we give the URL as `../submod`. This way, when we do `git submodule init`, git generates an absolute URL for the submodule from the relative URL we gave in `.gitmodules`.

Answer (score 0):

Other then using gitosis as gbacon said, you can change your workflow a little.

When working on public branch (branch shared with others on the team) always use sub-modules from public branch of single official repository. And instead of using your username to pull from sub-module's repository use one common user shared by the team. This user will have read-only access to the repositories.

The drawback is, if you want to push to common sub-module repository, you need to do it from another working copy using your username. That's sometimes a problem, and sometimes it's not. Depends on relation between modules and on your process.

Comment: Okay, but how could we have a third user with the SSH keys, because at the moment it uses whatever's in Drive:\Users\Me\.ssh\file.pvk (on the client) etc. If we have a shared user account on the server, how would our client machines have to be set up?

Comment: @tentux: Have you tried the other way around?  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys can contain multiple public keys.

Comment: @tentux: I reread your question and had a thought. Why are you adding "user@" part to your submodule URL? If your usernames on server and client machines are the same, git will simply use current user name for authentication.

Comment: Good thought, we will give this a try. The "user@" part was created (I think by GitExtensions). Will update this thread with the result.